# Sub-optimal Samba speeds (for external NTFS HDD)

Tags: usb, hard-drive, samba, usb3

So, I'm trying to setup a Samba share on my R Pi 4 for my home network. I'd really like it it be Samba because at lease 1 Win10 machine is involved.

The setup is as follows:

- External USB 3 HDD is attached to the R Pi and auto-mounted via `/etc/fstab`.
- Samba server is set up to use this disk as a share: https://pastebin.com/uYWW70Ez

I have both devices on a 1Gbps Ethernet network, still transfer speeds are:

- Upload to Samba share: **~32MB/s**
- Download from Samba share: **~19MB/s** (it actually starts with ~60MB/s, but then heavily drops and fluctuates randomly between 9MB/s and 24MB/s)

During Samba upload/download R Pi CPU is no more than 50% loaded; and there's spenty of memory as well.

I'm pretty sure it's not HDD (although it being NTFS-formatted). `dd` tests tell it can perform a lot faster at the R Pi:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null bs=16M count=100 status=progress iflag=direct
...
1677721600 bytes (1.7 GB, 1.6 GiB) copied, 18.5466 s, 90.5 MB/s
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/usb_hdd/blob bs=16M count=100 status=progress oflag=direct
...
1677721600 bytes (1.7 GB, 1.6 GiB) copied, 22.2178 s, 75.5 MB/s
$ sudo dd if=/mnt/usb_hdd/blob of=/dev/null bs=16M count=100 status=progress
...
1677721600 bytes (1.7 GB, 1.6 GiB) copied, 23.3002 s, 72.0 MB/s
```

This is also not a network: write/read to/from a Samba share backed up by a RAM-disk are >100MB/s.

On the other hand, I've discovered Pi's internal SD card being terribly slow **which correlates with a terrible Samba upload speed to HDD**:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=~/blob bs=16M count=100 status=progress oflag=direct
...
1677721600 bytes (1.7 GB, 1.6 GiB) copied, 90.1067 s, 18.6 MB/s
$ sudo dd if=~/blob of=/dev/null bs=16M count=100 status=progress
...
1677721600 bytes (1.7 GB, 1.6 GiB) copied, 36.7608 s, 45.6 MB/s
```

So what the hell is going on here?? And how do I improve my precious Samba setup speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG, seems like I've solved it! Now both Samba read/write are at ~70MB/s.

To improve **writing**: add `big_writes` option to your `/etc/fstab` mounting NTFS HDD.
Note that this option is [deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/544864/288995) since 2016 (libfuse 3.0.0), but R Pi is still using 2.9.9.

To improve **reading**: add `write cache size = 2097152` to your `/etc/samba/smb.cfg` (looked up [here](https://coderwall.com/p/2ufa0g/fix-samba-read-and-write-performance-issues))

Comment: Better still DON'T USE NTFS. It performs poorly on Linux - use ext4.

Comment: @Milliways is correct. There is absolutely no need to use NTFS as the file system for your Samba drive - use the native `ext4`. And `dd` is notoriously slow (inefficient) with small block sizes... that said, your question might benefit if it included an explanation of what `dd` has to do with this.

Comment: @Seamus, do you mean 16Mb blocks are small for `dd` test? At least that's roughly the size duplicity uses to write files to this share. Thus it's representative to me.  
Regarding NTFS: my reading of `dd` results is no matter the filesystem it won't read faster than 90MB/s (see the first `dd`) - that's only 20MB/s faster than what I have with NTFS now. The disk was already NTFS, I was lazy to reformat and the majority of devices are on WiFi - they won't notice ) Although the real argument against NTFS is fragmentation...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing this (I don't have enough points to comment so I'm using the answer method). Your suggestion of write cache size = 2097152 helped a bit (but not enough).
I'm hoping / praying for a vast NTFS performance improvement with Paragon's release of an NTFS driver, progress of which I have been tracking at this website:
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_topic&q=Linux%20Storage